# WebMatrix - Inner Join and Foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, razor, foreach, webmatrix

i'm trying to do something which i see a lot, but im having trouble working out the best way to do it.

I have the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Property_Info INNER JOIN RateInfo ON Property_Info.PropertyID=RateInfo.RateID"
```

From this, i do the following foreach loop to show all my properties.

```
foreach(var row in queryResults){
<div class="row">
    <h4>@row.PropertyName</h4>
    <h5>Prices from: xxxx</h5>
    </div>
}
```

The problem i have, is that i need to do a "SELECT TOP 1" on the joined table (RateInfo) to show the lowest price for each property. I need to show this in the foreach loop where i have put xxxx

Do i need to write a seperate SQL query? if so, how do i bind it to the appropriate entry in the foreach loop.

Table Info:

Property_Info Table -
PropertyID,
PropertyName

RateInfo Table - 
PropertyID (this matches the PropertyID from the other table),
RateID,
RateName,
RateValue

Comment: Can you post the schema of the two tables involved?

Comment: done, hopefully thats what you need? as i was trying to explain. Each property can have several rates associated with it, but i just want to show the cheapest (or most expensive) rate in my foreach loop. So that every property that gets generated by the foreach loop show's it's cheapest rate?

Comment: Just to be sure I've understood you, `Property_Info.PropertyID=RateInfo.RateID` in your question should be `Property_Info.PropertyID=RateInfo.PropertyID`, correct?

Comment: Ah, yes sorry! i was trying some stuff out, so must have forgot to revert that back. well spotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    pi.PropertyID,
    pi.PropertyName,
    MIN(ri.Rate) AS LowestRate,
    MAX(ri.Rate) AS HighestRate
FROM
    Property_Info pi
INNER JOIN
    RateInfo ri ON pi.PropertyID = ri.PropertyID
GROUP BY
    pi.PropertyID,
    pi.PropertyName
```

Changes from your code are using aliasing on the table names so that they are easier to refer to again and using a `GROUP BY` to let us perform aggregate functions on the data in the `RateInfo` table. Hopefully that's what you needed?

Comment: That is exactly what i needed, it's worked perfectly. I've never used aliases before, but looks like it'll make my queries look a little neater. Also, i've never used GROUP BY, but it works perfectly. I'll need to have a little read up on that to find out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the table structures it's a bit difficult, but I am assuming that RateInfo as a unique Id for each row. That being the case:

```
SELECT * FROM Property_Info pi
cross JOIN RateInfo ri
where ri.RateId = (select max(ri2.RateId) from RateInfo ri2 where ri2.RateId = pi.PropertyId)
```

...or instead of the max(ri2.Id) you could use:

```
select top 1 ri2.RateId from RateInfo ri2...
```

Cheers -

SELECT * FROM Property_Info pi
    cross JOIN RateInfo ri
    where ri.Id = (select max(ri2.Id) from RateInfo ri2 where ri2.RateId = pi.PropertyId)

Note the **ri.Id = (select max(ri2.Id**)  .... This Id is the unique field I assume exists on RateInfo.
Apologies..

Comment: thanks! im not sure what you're achieving with the pi and ri, but i'll give it a go, and hopefully i'll get the results i need. Thanks :)

Comment: The pi and ri (and ri2) are 'corelation' names: basically shorthand names for the tables. That's how you can get the same table in twice as I have with RateInfo but be utterly unambiguous about which one you mean.

Comment: Also - sorry but there's a typo: I've edited the answer to correct it otherwise it won't work.

Comment: For performance reasons this is a terrible approach. That sub-query in the `WHERE` clause is going to be executed once for every result of the (completely unnecessary) `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Actually, depending on the DBMS, it doesn't. Looking at it in SQL Server 2012 the query plan for a similar query shows a nested loop joining the two tables - not the most efficient, but nothing like 'once for every result'. Modern RDBMS's don't behave like that.